# cockpit manage networking interfaces from the "Unmanaged Interfaces" list

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, configuration-management

- How can i move interfaces between the "Interfaces" and  "Unmanaged Interfaces
  " section in cockpit ?
- Under what circumstances are interfaces moved to the "Unmanaged Interfaces
  " section ?

I run ubuntu 16.04 on a x68 cpu based firewall with 4+1 eth interfaces, 1 wifi.
When i installed cockpit, ALL the physical interfaces (eth0-4; wifi) were in the "Interfaces" section and could be configured.

Some software interfaces (like tunl0) were and still are, in the "Unmanaged Interfaces" section (since they are configured by the respective software).

Now, ALL hardware interfaces, except wifi are in the "Unmanaged Interfaces" list. 2 Things changed:

- i configured 3 eth ports with IP settings / routes and added dhcp service to 2 of them
- i deactivated 2 interfaces in cockpit and they moved to the "Unmanaged Interfaces" section.
- wifi was not configured , but deactivated and stayed in the "Interfaces" section

I found no specific information to the network management in cockpit either on the cockpit documentation or on stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

- You must ensure that no other service that wants to configure the network is running; in fact, multiple networking services will conflict. You can find a list of the currently running services with `systemctl --type=service` and then `stop` them.
- Also You have to remove/comment out every interface you wish to config through cockpit in `/etc/networking/interfaces`
- Then install and enable networkmanager package.

Everything about setup Network Manager is describe here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager 
https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager